# How to join data from a CSV to a shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins

I'm new to GIS and new to StackedExchange.

I need help joining a **CSV** of Accessibility data to a LSOA shapefile in **QGIS**.

The process explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis?rq=1) does not work for me and I don't know why. The **mmqgis plugin** and the **Joins** feature in QGIS both provide me with either an empty Shapefile or an empty CSV file.

I'm trying to map statistics related to accessibility to hospitals from the Department for Transport. The data can be downloaded from [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/department-for-transport/series/transport-accessibility-statistics--3) and is in **CSV** format and is georeferenced by Lower Super Output Area (LSOA), with one column of LSOA codes and the rest are the separate statistics (time taken to get to nearest hospital, for example).

I also have a LSOA shapefile from [here](https://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/handle/10672/320), which obviously has the **exact same list of LSOA codes**.

How can I join the two datasets so that I can map the accessibility stats for each LSOA with a range of colours? I've tried using the 'Join' feature but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

The first image shows the Accessibility data, note the LSOA data in the first column which matches the LSOA data in the Shapefile and the last column is what I want to map/Join. The second image shows the data associated with the LSOA shapefile, note the LSOA data matches that in the Accessibility data. As far as I know the data type in each file matches. What I want to do is map the data in, say, column 5 of the Accessibility data onto the LSOA shapefile.

[image]

[image]

Comment: related: Join non-spatial CSV to spatial data in QGIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Please use the search before posting a question. You find a solution for your problem here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Please be more specific about "can't seem to get it to work". Do the values in both files really match? What happens if you use try do perform the join?

Comment: @Curlew I have spent the past two days following the instructions in that link at it doesn't seem to fix my problem. Hence the question.

Comment: @underdark Yes, the LSOA values in both files match. When I follow the instructions in the link you and Curlew posted (using the MMQGIS plugin) I end up with shapefile with no information. The attribute table shows the correct headings, but there is no data, just an empty shapefile. I've also tried using the Joins tool in the Properties option and that does the same. Is there any more info I can give you guys to explain? I tried to upload files or screenshots but I can't yet as I'm a new user.

Comment: Hi @user14519, if you upload images to imgur.com and paste the link someone can insert them in your question. I would check that the data type in each file matches (e.g. numbers or characters in both). This can be a common reason why joins fail.

Comment: are the attribute columns for the join the same type? string integer etc

Comment: @djq Thanks for the idea. The images are at: http://i.imgur.com/vM2ffxC.png and http://i.imgur.com/ufDdO5n.png  The first image shows the Accessibility data, note the LSOA data in the first column which matches the LSOA data in the Shapefile and the last column is what I want to map/Join. The second image shows the data associated with the LSOA shapefile, note the LSOA data matches that in the Accessibility data. As far as I know the data type in each file matches. What I want to do is map the data in, say, column 5 of the Accessibility data onto the LSOA shapefile.

Comment: "What I want to do is map the data in, say, column 5 of the Accessibility data onto the LSOA shapefile." ... That's not possible. QGIS will always add all columns. Are you really joining on the two code columns? I don't see why that wouldn't work.