# Table calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have a shapefile with the attribute "yield". I need to know the math difference between yield (id1) and yield (id2)... then yield (id2) and yield (id3) and so on... I hope you understand what I mean.

In Excel it is easy to handle. But I do not want to export and import the files.

Comment: I think you will need some python scripting for that.

Comment: @Pimpel, make math difference in Excel (save result in csv or dbf table), then Join this table to shape-file (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

How about a solution in Spatialite? Import your shapefile into a spatialite DB, lets call it "polys". Add a column to hold the differences:

```
ALTER TABLE polys ADD COLUMN diffs real;
```

Now this UPDATE will populate the diffs column with the differences between each consecutive row:

```
UPDATE polys SET diffs=(
SELECT p1.yield-p2.yield
FROM polys AS p1, polys AS p2
WHERE p1.ROWID=p2.ROWID-1 AND p2.ROWID>=2);
```