# Spatially joining polygon fields onto point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, csv, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I have gridded depth points in CSV format that I'm trying to add other map data to, in additional columns. I've tried joining fields, hoping that I could link the shapefile data to the CSV, but when I try to display the CSV by graduated symbols based on the new fields, it goes blank. I used @Nathan's tips from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/join-non-spatial-csv-to-spatial-data-in-qgis), but imported the CSV as CSV since I want to add map info to that, rather than adding CSV info to a map.

See this picture below for the sea bottom temperature & salinity voronois by month, underneath the CSV points (a sample subset), with the joins already made. I added columns on the CSV for each of the fields i'm intending to append.

[image: DESCRIPTION]

I also tried spatial joins as per [this](http://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/joining-layers-in-qgis/) however it says the layers aren't the same CRS (I checked, they are), then gets to 15% and hangs.

I also also tried spatial join through [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) but it hit a python error. I can try this again and look to debug the problem if this is the right way to go.

In short: appending polygon data as fields on a points-grid CSV: what's the best way in QGIS 2.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best tool for this job in my experience is [Add polygon attributes to points in the Processing toolbox](http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/02/add-polygon-attributes-to-points-vs-join-attributes-by-location/). If it does not work directly with the CSV, just save the points to a Shapefile before you run the spatial join.

Answer (score 5):

Processing > Toolbox > SAGA > Vector point tools > Add polygon attributes to points:

[image]

Then you select the attribute from polygon data to add:

[image]

You can repeat the process with the result to add more than one attribute.