# QGis polygon to points different CRS problems

Tags: qgis-2, csv, coordinate-system, spatial-join

I'm trying to join the values from polygons onto a grid of points. I had this problem solved [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86444/how-to-spatially-join-polygon-fields-onto-a-point-layer-in-qgis) by @Underdark , however a few layers weren't working. It seemed they were all British National Grid CRS [EPSG:27700] whereas my project & points CRS is WGS84. The error was:

> Oooops! The following output layers could not be open. Result:
>   C:\path\outputname.shp. The above files could not be opened, which probably
>   indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed
>   algorithm. Checking the log information might help you see why those
>   layers were not created as expected. This algorithm requires SAGA to be
>   run. A test to check if SAGA is correctly installed and configured in
>   your system has been performed, with the following result: SAGA seems
>   to be correctly installed and configured.

So I tried re-saving the BNG layers as WGS84 as per @Underdark's guide [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23856/what-is-up-with-qgis-buffer-tool-units/23863#23863), the result of which looks fine, however after then adding polygons to points and saving the output as CSV (as I did successfully for the rest), there are no data in the field column.

Can anyone think why this might be? Or what I could do to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Painful that I didn't think to do this earlier:

Convert the POINTS field to BNG and then append the points to that, all projected as BNG. QGis will keep the order of points the same, and pre-prend the CRS (BNG) X/Ys before the Lat/Longs, preserving them for your CSV later.

Still don't know why converting the shapefiles to WGS84 didn't work, but a solution's a solution.