# QGIS Spatial Сross Join attributes

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, spatial-join

I have a set of `LineStrings` (streets) and a set of rectangles (atlas pages extents) that could overlap each-other.

And now I want to create a legend for an atlas like

```
street1, pages: 1,2
street2, pages: 2,3

or

page1, streets: 1,2,3,5
page2, streets: 2,4,5,6
```

Page numbers are rectangles' attribute. So I need to spatially join attributes, but relations between streets and pages are many-to-many and QGIS Spatial attributes join allows me only two options: write first occurrence or aggregate over attributes values.

In other words, I want to get the analog of Postgis spatial join like below and write it out (in `.csv` or other format):

```
select page.number, street.number, street.name 
from
   street, page
where 
   ST_INTERSECTS(street.geom, page.geom)
```

I could run a python script that will iterate over pages, take streets, and write cross joined attributes into a `.csv` file. But maybe somebody already done this before and has published a solution?

Comment: In addition: I've checked Anita's (underdark) solution with Saga script http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86444/how-to-spatially-join-polygon-fields-onto-a-point-layer-in-qgis there is the same problem. I have more than one polygon for every highway (even if I take points, I will have more than one page for some points)

Comment: There are some published solutions, but all the ones I'm familiar with are for ArcGIS: http://support.esri.com/de/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39710 and http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/11/08/creating-street-name-indexes/ and [implemented in the Fire Run book tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.1/index.html#//028s000000st000000). It sounds like you've already created a script that works for you, but these other resources might suggest alternative means/methods or scripts that could be adapted.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/11/08/creating-street-name-indexes/ is what I want. The only obstacle is that it's for ArcGIC

Answer (score 1):

I've made a script for this task https://github.com/kiselev-dv/QGIS-Processing/blob/attributes_crossjoin/scripts/spatial_cross_join_attributes.py