# Locate points into polygons

Tags: qgis

I have a trajectory and a map that I have divided in segments. I want to locate each point (using for its id its time-stamp) to the appropriate segment, using qgis. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: This post : [How to spatially join polygon fields onto a point layer in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/86444/64955) might help you.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].