# Give points attribute based on unique polygon

Tags: polygon, point, layers, analysis

I have a problem that I can not solve. I've tried to find a solution in this forum, but with no sucess.

I have one layer with points and one layer with polygons. The point layer have information regarding population and the polygons have an unique ID. What I want to do is to give all points within a polygon the same unique ID as the polygon. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86444/spatially-joining-polygon-fields-onto-point-layer-in-qgis answer your question

Comment: What software/APIs do you have available? Spatial joining is a very common operation but the procedure is dependent on your software/API.