# Displaying Geocoded data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geocoding

[image]I have a CSV file with geocoded data that I would like to display in QGIS.  How do I open this file?  When I go to add CSV layer it asks for X and Y co-ordinates which I do not have as the data is geocoded?

Comment: Geocoded data usually has a pair of coordinates such as X/Y or lat/lon - what is your stored in?

Comment: A screenshot of your header and first pair of rows could be helpful.

Comment: Geocoding usually means that parts of the data can be used to locate it. Yours might have for example a postal code or an address. This will not be possible to directly import in QGIS without other data as the reference frame.

Comment: The CSV file has a column called Geo_code with data in the following format: E00024141.  The data is from Ordnance Survey Output Areas.

Comment: I have added an image to the original post

Comment: In order to display that data, you need another layer in which there are geometry features that also have this GEO_CODE field. Without it, there is no way for your GIS to know where that code is located.

Comment: What country are the geo codes for?

Comment: England - Its Ordnance Survey Data

Answer (score 1):

What you are having as GEO_CODE is code for [census output area](https://census.ukdataservice.ac.uk/use-data/guides/boundary-data).

First you need to get actual geo data, think its avalible on that page.

Areas are obviously polygons so next you need to decide if that's what you need or you want points. If you want points you can calculate centroids out of polygons.

Next step will be [joining](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/joining-non-spatial-csv-file-to-spatial-data-shapefile-using-qgis) of CSV table data with geometry layer. For this you will use GEO_CODE attribut.