# Adding field in vector layer from attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, attribute-joins, vector-layer

I have an attribute table named *'data.shp'* and a vector layer *'pop.shp'*.

The *'data.shp'* has the following fields `"ID"`, `"value1"`, `"value2"`

The *'pop.shp'* has the `"ID"` field (same with the *'data.shp'*)

I want to update *'pop.shp'* and add the fields `"value1"`, `"value2"` from *'data.shp'* where `"ID"` (from *'data.shp'*) is equal to `"ID"` (from *'pop.shp'*).

How could I do that in QGIS?

Comment: Have you checked this tutorial [Performing Table Joins](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html)? Start from Step `#12`, inclusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining non-spatial CSV file to spatial data (shapefile) using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/joining-non-spatial-csv-file-to-spatial-data-shapefile-using-qgis), mainly [Nathan W's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10465/99589).

Comment: @Taras it seems `sql` tag was removed. That tag is essential to distinguish Nat's question from the linked one. Thanks!

Comment: @Kazuhito, shall I place it back? However, I did not find out anything related to `sql` in the gist of the question itself, is not it? Can you clarify this for me, please?

Comment: @Kazuhito I'm not sure the `sql` tag is that relevant even to the linked questions. The joins can be done without it.

Comment: @Taras I see your point. But a tag is important part of the question.

Comment: @Kazuhito, what shall we do then? =)

Comment: @Taras I will edit the tag to put `sql` back in.

Comment: @GabrielC. In some cases there are multiple possible solutions. A tag can tell us  preferred approach. (As Taras says, it is much clear if mentioned in the body of question.)

Comment: @Kazuhito Maybe, but I would say it's a case of [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP might just not have known about how easily joins can be done and expected needing SQL. In any case, clarifying in the question will steer answers towards what he wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QGIS has built-in table join capabilities. If you want to add fields from a table (data.shp) into another layer (pop.shp), then go this way:

- Right click on pop.shp -> Properties -> Joins -> "+"
- Choose relevant layer and key field for the join
- Check which fields you want to add
- Click OK

The attribute table from your pop.shp layer should now include the data you need. To make this permanent, save the layer as a new file.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another solution implies the usage of a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

With the following query, it is possible *to update 'pop.shp' and add the fields `"value1"`, `"value2"` from 'data.shp'*.

```sql
SELECT
    pop.*,
    data.value1,
    data.value2
FROM
    "pop"
LEFT JOIN "data"
    ON pop.id = data.id
```

---

**References:**

- [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
- [SQL LEFT JOIN Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)