# Uploading CSV file without coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, import, united-kingdom

I am very much a QGIS beginner and want a vector layer of food deserts in England, but the only data I can find is in CSV format with no shapefile https://data.cdrc.ac.uk/dataset/e-food-desert-index.

I have tried to upload the CSV file through delimited text, but the CSV file has no long or lat coordinates, so nothing appears on the map.

How do I get around this, or does anyone know of a UK food desert shapefile I can use?

Answer (score 7):

Your data is related to "LSOAs in England and Wales and Data Zones in Scotland." (from the readme) so you need to download some LSOA boundaries (and Data Zones in Scotland). Then you can make a **join** between the two datasets and will be able to draw maps of your food desserts :-)

There are plenty of answers on this site to help you get started, for example [Joining non-spatial CSV file to spatial data (shapefile) using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/joining-non-spatial-csv-file-to-spatial-data-shapefile-using-qgis)

Comment: This is very useful, thank you :)